# Java installation(Java 8 & 19) not recognized by Homebrew Jenv

Tags: java, installation, homebrew, jenv

I have installed Java 8 & 19 using Homebrew Jenv on MacOS Monterey following their [instruction](https://jenv.be). I wanted to use jenv for two different projects that I need to switch b/n the two versions.

Once I added the Home env't variable using

```
$ echo 'export PATH="$HOME/.jenv/bin:$PATH"' >> ~/.bash_profile
$ echo 'eval "$(jenv init -)"' >> ~/.bash_profile
```

then I went to add this command:

```
jenv add /Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk-19.0.1.jdk/Contents/Home and

 jenv add /Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk17011.jdk/Contents/Home
```

The result I got is: **/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk-19.0.1.jdk/Contents/Home is not a valid path to java installation**

and

**/Users/docho/.jenv/versions/openjdk64-1.8.0.292: No such file or directory**

What am I missing ?

**EDIT:**
When I run java --version I see: `openjdk version "1.8.0_292"`

However when I run jenv versions I see this:

```
 * system (set by /Users/docho/.jenv/version)
```

JAVA_HOME also points to: `/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/adoptopenjdk-8.jdk/Contents/Home`

But PATH variable has no Java related content:

```
/usr/local/bin:/usr/bin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/sbin:/Users/docho/.local/share/solana/install/active_release/bin:/Library/Apple/usr/bin:/Users/docho/.cargo/bin
```

Comment: I'm in the same exact situation